# Using parameters for messages in Spring validation annotations

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

In this kind of code that adds a validation constraint to an attribute of my command class:

```
@NotBlank(message="{xxx.constraints.username.required}")
```

how can I pass parameters to the message? In fact I would like the message to be a template, is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I am almost 4 years late but I am still interested how you went around this.

Comment: I wish I remembered! There is no easy way to do it easily with the latest Spring version? What about using {0}, {1} etc. as placeholders in the message and find the way to pass the arguments in the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (Spring Expression Language).

```
@NotBlank(message="#{T(com.my.package.MyUtil).getMessage()}")
```

The above would call a static method `getMessage()` from the `com.my.package.MyUtil` class.

Comment: Actually I am more thinking of something like <spring:message code="xxx.constraints.username.required" arguments="arg1, arg2"/> then in ValidationMessages.properties I would have xxx.constraints.username.required=Some text {0] and {1} blah blah

Comment: Take a look at Spring EL.  It may be able to do just what you are looking for.  What I have posted in my answer was just an example of ***one*** thing that can be done with SpEL.